# Get Specific Item From Array

Tags: php, mysql, facebook-graph-api

I am testing with the Facebook API. I am trying to return the amount of friends with this array:

```
$friends = $facebook->api(array(
    "method"    => "fql.query",
    "query"     => "SELECT friend_count FROM user WHERE uid = me()"
));
```

Then I display it: `print_r($friends);`
It displays as this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [friend_count] => 167
        )

)
```

I want to just get that number to display, the 167 in my case. I'm not quite sure how to do that. Any help is greatly appreciate. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
echo $friends[0]['friend_count'];
```